# Is there a way to host a node.js server without a public IP?

Tags: node.js, dynamic, ip, private, public

I've made a simple Node.js app that i can host locally and using services like evennode. Now I want to do this on my home PC and it seems like a simple task to do - just port forward and get a domain name.

However, my problem is that i don't have a public IP. My ISP uses private/dynamic IP addresses which makes hosting impossible(?).

Is there a program or service that can fix my problem? I've found some for Apache/SQL servers but nothing for Node.js

Comment: Are you speaking about a free service? or are you down to solutions requiring a payment?

Comment: free, or without any service at all if possible. I'm trying noip currently

Comment: Is this a generic website or is it going to be accessed by someone in particular?

Comment: it's just me messing around trying to learn web application etc

Comment: If the other end of the comunication has a public IP you can use SSH from the machine hosting the server to the other. If both doesn't have a public IP you need a central node.